# javalite async event processing failed with error [client] - AMQ214008: Failed to handle packet java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: activejdbc, activemq-artemis, javalite, activeweb

```
    please anybody help to fix this issue?<br/>
    **I am getting issue [client] - AMQ214008: Failed to handle packet java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException while processing the command data in javalite async?**<br/>

            [2018-03-30 10:27:16,303] - [DEBUG] [client] - Calling close on session ClientSessionImpl [name=d13aa760-33d6-11e8-b4fb-844bf530b8f3, username=null, closed=false, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@58e64301, metaData=(jms-session=,)]@6a6c5fb3 <br/>
            [2018-03-30 10:27:16,306] - [DEBUG] [server] - QueueImpl[name=jms.queue.eventQueue, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=70d74287-3283-11e8-8a66-844bf530b8f3]]@39533a61 doing deliver. messageReferences=0 <br/>
            [2018-03-30 10:27:16,308] - [DEBUG] [client] - calling cleanup on ClientSessionImpl [name=d13aa760-33d6-11e8-b4fb-844bf530b8f3, username=null, closed=false, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@58e64301, metaData=(jms-session=,)]@6a6c5fb3 <br/>
            [2018-03-30 10:27:16,335] - [DEBUG] [HttpAsyncRequestExecutor] - http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE] [content length: 42355; pos: 42355; completed: true] <br/>
            [2018-03-30 10:27:16,336] - [DEBUG] [ThreadLocalRandom] - -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0xad1a1d5891abf66a <br/>
            **[2018-03-30 10:27:16,337] - [ERROR] [client] - AMQ214008: Failed to handle packet <br/>
            java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException<br/>
            at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(Unknown Source)**<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.handleCompressedMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:600)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.handleMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:532)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.handleReceiveMessage(ClientSessionImpl.java:824)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.remoting.SessionContext.handleReceiveMessage(SessionContext.java:97)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.handleReceivedMessagePacket(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:712)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext.access$400(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:111)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQSessionContext$ClientSessionPacketHandler.handlePacket(ActiveMQSessionContext.java:755)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:594)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:368)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:350)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1140)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnection$1.run(InVMConnection.java:183)<br/>
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100)<br/>
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)<br/>
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)<br/>
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)<br/>
               <br/><br/>
```

> **When i execute the code in standalone project, its working fine. But while running the same in Tomcat server its throwing the above
>   error..?**
>           
>             Source Code is below
>             public class TestCommand extends Command 
>             {
>                 private TestEvent event;
>
> ```
>           public TestCommand(MsgEvent event) 
>           {
>           this.event = (TestEvent)event;
>           }
>
>           public TestCommand() 
>           {
>           } 
>
>           @Override
>           public void execute() 
>           {   
>               //code stuff
>           }
>
>       }
>       <br/><br/>          
>       async = new Async(filePath, false, new QueueConfig("eventQueue", new CommandListener(), threadCount));
>           <br/>
>       async.start();
>       <br/>
>       public void test(EventCommand ev)
>       {
>           async.send("eventQueue", ev);
>       }       <br/>
> ```
>
> **Following libraries are loaded into classpath**
>
> please anybody help to fix this issue?

Comment: Obviously you have some sort of a class path issue with libraries loaded in Tomcat. I added Artemis related tags so that the Artemis team takes notice. If you are using Maven, you might want to use a Maven dependency plugin to investigate classpath conflicts: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: we are not using maven and directly added the dependent jars in classpath. following libraries are loaded artemis-commons-1.2.0.jar artemis-core-client-1.2.0.jar artemis-jms-client-1.2.0.jar  artemis-jms-server-1.2.0.jar artemis-journal-1.2.0.jar  artemis-selector-1.2.0.jar  artemis-server-1.2.0.jar  javax.jms-api-2.0.jar  netty-all-4.1.7.Final.jar  xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar  xstream-1.4.7.jar  javalite-async-1.14-20160920.063953-45.jar  javalite-common-1.4.14.j7-20180227.053758-4.jar

Comment: that was a suggestion, you still need to figure out the conflict on your classpath, or refer to https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/community.html. In other words, this is not a JavaLite issue.

Comment: @ipolevoy: Artemis 2.5 version supported by which version of javalite async and jdk?

Comment: Please, see https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/blob/master/javalite-async/pom.xml#L17 and: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/blob/master/pom.xml#L50

Comment: Also, the JavaLite version 1.14 is very old, upgrade to 2.0

Comment: @ipolevoy: thanks for the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evidence suggests to me that when this code is executed in Tomcat it is using a different java.nio.ByteBuffer implementation than when it is run standalone (perhaps due to different versions of Netty). The [code causing the exception](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/1.2.0/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/client/impl/ClientConsumerImpl.java#L600) is calling [java.nio.ByteBuffer.array()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array()) which is not required to be implemented (i.e. throwing an UnsupportedOperationException is valid here). This was dealt with in Artemis via [this commit](https://github.com/jbertram/activemq-artemis/commit/577620533d6a39ba196a69b4464616e1e6b5da5f) which is available in Artemis 1.4. That said, there's no reason to use such an old version of Artemis. I would recommend you upgrade to the latest 2.5 release as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much justin, its problem with netty version. after downgrading the netty version to netty-all-4.0.32.Final from netty-all-4.1.7.Final, this error is fixed

Comment: Can you vote the answer up since it proved correct? Also, I would still recommend you upgrade ASAP.

Comment: @JustinBertram, JavaLite pulls Artemis version 2.3: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb/blob/master/javalite-async/pom.xml#L17. Somehow he swapped it for the older version

Comment: Thanks JustinBertram and ipolevoy for your time. we are using jdk 1.7,it seems the corresponding javalite async jars version 1.14.  I think even we have to change jdk to 1.8 for using latest version of javallite and Artemis. :-)

Comment: Seeing that updates for Java 7 haven't been publicly available since early 2015 I'd say you're probably due for an upgrade there as well.